# Can't get Picasso to work due to some errors

Tags: android, picasso

I'm trying to turn URLs that I get from JSON to images. I tried to use Picasso but it gives me the

error: no suitable method found for into(int)
        Picasso.get().load(rssObject.getItems().get(position).getThumbnail()).into(R.id.imageView);
                                                                             ^
    method RequestCreator.into(Target) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to Target)
    method RequestCreator.into(ImageView) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to ImageView)

class FeedViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener,View.OnLongClickListener

This is my code, desperately in need of quick help, thanks

```
public TextView txtTitle,txtPubDate,txtContent,txtAuthor,txtThumbnail;
private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;
public ImageView imageView;



public FeedViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    txtTitle=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
    txtPubDate=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPubDate);
    txtAuthor=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtAuthor);
    txtContent=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtContent);
    txtThumbnail=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtThumbnail);
     imageView=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
}

public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
    this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

itemClickListener.onClick(v,getAdapterPosition(),false);
}

@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    itemClickListener.onClick(v,getAdapterPosition(),true);
    return true;
}
```

}

public class FeedAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter{

```
private RSSObject rssObject;
private Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public FeedAdapter(RSSObject rssObject, Context mContext) {
    this.rssObject = rssObject;
    this.mContext = mContext;
    inflater =LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
}

@Override
public FeedViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row,parent,false);
    return new FeedViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(FeedViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Picasso.get().load(rssObject.getItems().get(position).getThumbnail()).into(R.id.imageView);
    holder.txtTitle.setText(rssObject.getItems().get(position).getTitle());
    holder.txtPubDate.setText(rssObject.getItems().get(position).getPubDate());
    holder.txtAuthor.setText(rssObject.getItems().get(position).getAuthor());
    holder.txtContent.setText(rssObject.getItems().get(position).getContent());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return rssObject.items.size();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Picasso.get().load(your picture).getThumbnail().into(imageView);
```